# how to select table column without specify name of column and can apply same condition for all column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, union

How to select table column without specify name of column and can apply same condition for all column.
I am Using following SQL query. Can I achieve same result using single line query in SQL server

```
SELECT FEE.admissionfees AS AMT
    ,'Admission Fee' amtType
FROM tblFeesDetails FEE
INNER JOIN tblStudentFeeSheet STF ON FEE.feesId = STF.feeId
WHERE feeId = 1
    AND enrollMentNo = 'EDU0001'
    AND FEE.admissionfees != 0

UNION

SELECT FEE.electricityAndBuildingMaintanance AS AMT
    ,'Elec. & Buld. Maint. Fee' amtType
FROM tblFeesDetails FEE
INNER JOIN tblStudentFeeSheet STF ON FEE.feesId = STF.feeId
WHERE feeId = 1
    AND enrollMentNo = 'EDU0001'
    AND FEE.electricityAndBuildingMaintanance != 0

UNION

SELECT FEE.functions AS AMT
    ,'Functions & Other Act. Fee' amtType
FROM tblFeesDetails FEE
INNER JOIN tblStudentFeeSheet STF ON FEE.feesId = STF.feeId
WHERE feeId = 1
    AND enrollMentNo = 'EDU0001'
    AND FEE.functions != 0

UNION

SELECT FEE.gamesAndExtraCurriculam AS AMT
    ,'Games & other Curriculam' amtType
FROM tblFeesDetails FEE
INNER JOIN tblStudentFeeSheet STF ON FEE.feesId = STF.feeId
WHERE feeId = 1
    AND enrollMentNo = 'EDU0001'
    AND FEE.gamesAndExtraCurriculam != 0
```

Comment: You can get the same info. Use CASE in the select-list, and OR the WHERE clauses together. (BTW. you probably want UNION ALL in your original query.)

Comment: it is not possible to do what you ask: if you want to select a column you must tell the system which column...

Comment: Thanks to all for knowledgeable comments